# Questions regarding How do i tutorial (WPF/Entity Framework/ObservableCollections)

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, entity-framework

i watched [How Do I: Build a WPF Data Entry Form Using Entity Framework?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/dd776540.aspx)

very confused around 15:30. when the presenter said something like

> when you create a LINQ query, we wont get a rich collection ...

whats does she mean my "rich".

the start code looks like... whats wrong with that. even if i change `db.Customers.Execute(...)` with a LINQ query, the code still works. why the need for a new observable collection and why ListCollectionView instead of BindingListCollection view. whats the diff between the 2

```
// customerSource is a CollectionViewSource stored in Window.Resources
// db is of type OMSEntities (which is the Entity Collection Name, what does this mean?)
customerSource.Source = db.Customers.Execute(...);
this.view = (BindingListCollectionView) customerSource.View;
```

the code after looks like (~21:38)

```
results = from cust in db.Customers ...
customerData = new CustomerCollection(results, db);
customerSource.Source = customerData
view = (ListCollectionView) customerSource.View;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

She means that you'll get back an IEnumerable, which doesn't have any support for two way binding or extra facilities like notifications of add/remove events, that are available in other collection types.  So, the code is taking the IEnumerable and putting the results into a "richer" collection type that has those kinds of features.

Comment: but i find that if i replace `customerSource.Source = db.Customers.Execute(...)` with `customerSource.Source = from cust in db.Customers select cust` it still works fine. why did she use ListCollectionView instead of BindingListCollectionView? am i missing something? sorry not that i insist of BindingListCollectionView or something, i just dont understand the reason for the switch

Comment: Have you tried adding or removing rows and saving?  If you bind directly to the LINQ query, you're updates from the UI don't get saved.